# How do I exclude subdirectories from a project root in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am exploring a model where I codegen one `.iml` file per package in IntelliJ. For example, suppose I have the packages `com.example.foo`, `com.example.foo.bar`, and `com.example.foo.baz`. That means that in the `.iml` file for `com.example.foo`, I need:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$"
                isTestSource="false"
                packagePrefix="com.example.foo" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/bar" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/baz" />
</content>
```

Every time I add a new "sub-package" of `com.example.foo`, I have to add a new `<excludeFolder>` element to `<content>`. Is there any way to avoid this and just say "my source directory is the immediate directory and none of the subdirectories?"

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: could you respond that way outside of a comment so I can make that the OA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source root configuration is recursive, it's not possible to configure just a directory as Sources while excluding all its subdirectories.